# Footable js is not working with bootstrap datepicker js and tooltip

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-datepicker, footable, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

My Master page head

```
<link href="/Other/Bootstrap/bootstrap.min3.3.6.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/Css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/Css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/Css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/Css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/Css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/Css/plugins.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/JavaScript/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/JavaScript/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="/Other/Bootstrap/footable.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/Other/Bootstrap/footable.js"></script>
<link href="/Css/Sweetalert.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/JavaScript/sweetalert.js"></script>
<script src="/JavaScript/SweetPopup.js"></script>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    });
</script>
```

This is my Content page where I used footable on Gridview and dynamically adding row with asp controls.In on of the textbox I used datepicker .

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="page-title clearfix">
        <span class="h3"><i class=" fa fa-map-marker"></i>&nbsp; <strong>Student Information </strong></span>
    </div>
    <section style="background: #ddd">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row" style="min-height: 450px;">
                <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>

                            <asp:Panel ID="pnl1" runat="server" Visible="false">
                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <div class="form-group col-sm-12 margin-top-10">
                                            <label class="heading-small">Student Form Number</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
                                            <asp:GridView ID="Gridview1" runat="server" CssClass="table table-bordered" ShowFooter="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowCreated="Gridview1_RowCreated">
                                                <Columns>
                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="RowNumber" HeaderText="#" HeaderStyle-Width="40px" />
                                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Student Type" ControlStyle-CssClass="grid" HeaderStyle-Width="20%">
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <span class="Name"></span>
                                                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStype" runat="server" data-toggle="tooltip" title="स्टूडेंट टाइप का चयन करें" data-placement="bottom">
                                                                <asp:ListItem Text="Select" Value="-1" />
                                                                <asp:ListItem Text="Other" Value="Other" />
                                                                <asp:ListItem Text="XYZ Student" Value="XYZ Student" />
                                                            </asp:DropDownList>
                                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator8" runat="server" ValidationGroup="L" InitialValue="-1" ControlToValidate="ddlStype" ForeColor="Red" SetFocusOnError="true"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText=" Form no" ControlStyle-CssClass="grid" HeaderStyle-Width="20%">
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txt_fno" runat="server" placeholder=" Form No" onkeypress="return numericOnly(this);" data-toggle="tooltip" title="छात्र का फॉर्म नंबर दर्ज करें" data-placement="bottom" MaxLength="8" AutoComplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Here I use datepicker.But the javascript is not applied.

```
                                                                <div class="input-group">
                                                                    <span class="Name"></span>
                                                               <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span> <asp:TextBox ID="txt_date" runat="server" placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy" data-toggle="tooltip" title="चेक इन दिनांक दर्ज करें" data-placement="bottom" AutoComplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
                                                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt_date" ForeColor="red" ValidationGroup="L" SetFocusOnError="true"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                                                    </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Remark" ControlStyle-CssClass="grid" HeaderStyle-Width="30%">
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txt_remark" runat="server" placeholder="Enter Remark" AutoComplete="off" data-toggle="tooltip" title="टिप्पणी दर्ज करें" data-placement="bottom"></asp:TextBox>
                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                        <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                                                        <FooterTemplate>
                                                            <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server" data-toggle="tooltip" title="नई लाइन जोड़ने के लिए यहां क्लिक करे" data-placement="bottom" CssClass="btn hvr-shutter-out-horizontal  pull-right" Text="Add New Row" ValidationGroup="L" OnClick="ButtonAdd_Click" Style="padding: 8px 11px;" />
                                                        </FooterTemplate>
                                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" style="color:#f00; font-size:20px;"></i></asp:LinkButton>
                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                                </Columns>
                                            </asp:GridView>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
                                            <asp:Button ID="btn_submit" runat="server" data-toggle="tooltip" title="सबमिट करने के लिए यहां क्लिक करें" class="btn hvr-shutter-out-horizontal extra-btn-padding pull-right" ValidationGroup="L" Text="SUBMIT" OnClick="btn_submit_Click"></asp:Button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </asp:Panel>
                        </div>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
 <link href="/JavaScript/DatePicker/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/JavaScript/DatePicker/datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script src="/JavaScript/NumVal.js"></script>
<script src="/JavaScript/msg.js"></script>
 <script src="/JavaScript/DatePicker/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="/JavaScript/DatePicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
     <script src="/JavaScript/Tooltip.js"></script>
 <script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $('.table').footable();
         $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
         $(function () {
             $(".myDate").datepicker({
                 format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
                 startDate: "01-01-1990",
                 startView: 2,
                 clearBtn: !0,
                 forceParse: !1,
                 calendarWeeks: !0,
                 autoclose: !0,
                 todayHighlight: !0
             });
         })(jQuery);
     });
     function pageLoad(sender, args) {
         if (args.get_isPartialLoad()) {
             $('.table').footable();
             $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
             $(function () {
                 $(".myDate").datepicker({
                     format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
                     startDate: "01-01-1990",
                     startView: 2,
                     clearBtn: !0,
                     forceParse: !1,
                     calendarWeeks: !0,
                     autoclose: !0,
                     todayHighlight: !0
                 });
             })(jQuery);
         }
     }
  </script>
```

Comment: You haven't explained your circumstances very well & you also haven't included any of your markup.

I can tell you that having any number of FooTables, jQueryUI Tooltips & jQueryUI Datepickers on a page will work perfectly fine.

Due to the way that FooTable cycles things in and out of the DOM for filtering, paging & collapsing cells, there are chances that your other plugins may be destroyed if they fall within a filtered or paged row or a breakpoint hit cell.

Comment: Get a browser console going and start picking that HTML apart.